# joomla component does not work on my hosting account

Tags: php, joomla, components

I develop a custom joomla 1.5 component and it's working fine locally(wamp server ,php 5.3.5) and toolbar functions add/edit and delete does not work on my hosting account (apache ,php 5.2.16 )

I have two toolbars, when I click on the second toolbar it redirect to the first one

this is my code

controller.php

```
class GalGallerifficController extends JController
{

/**
 * Method to display the view
 *
 * @access    public
 */
 /**
 * constructor (registers additional tasks to methods)
 * @return void
 */
function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();

        // Register Extra tasks
        $this->registerTask( 'add'  , 'edit' );
}

/**
 * display the edit form
 * @return void
 */
function edit()
{
        JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'gallery' );
        JRequest::setVar( 'layout', 'form'  );
        JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', 1);

        parent::display();
}
 /**
 * remove record(s)
 * @return void
 */
function remove()
{
        $model = $this->getModel('gallery');
        if(!$model->delete()) {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Error: One or More Gallery(s) Could not be Deleted' );
        } else {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Gallery(s) Deleted' );
        }
        $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_galleriffic', $msg );
}
}
```

and the second controllers/galleryitems.php

```
class GalGallerifficControllerGalleryItems extends JController
{
function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();

        // Register Extra tasks
        $this->registerTask( 'add'  , 'edit' );
}
/**
 * display the edit form
 * @return void
 */
function edit()
{
        JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'galleryitem' );
        JRequest::setVar( 'layout', 'form'  );
        JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', 1);
        parent::display();
}
 /**
 * remove record(s)
 * @return void
 */
function remove()
{
    $model = $this->getModel('gallery');
    if(!$model->delete()) {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Error: One or More Gallery(s) Could not be Deleted' );
    } else {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Gallery(s) Deleted' );
    }

    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_galleriffic', $msg );
}
function display()
{
    parent::display();
}
}
```

and galleryitems view

```
class GalGallerifficViewGalleryItems extends JView
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        JToolBarHelper::title( JText::_( 'Galleriffic Gallery Items' ), 'generic.png' );
        JToolBarHelper::deleteList();
        JToolBarHelper::editListX();
        JToolBarHelper::addNewX();

        // Get data from the model
        $items =& $this->get( 'Data');
        $this->assignRef( 'items', $items );
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

any idea, why this happen ?

thanks in advance:)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work could you please be a bit more specific.  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: no errors Nick, it just redirect to the main view
there is two form(add gallery, add items) when click to add items it goes to add gallery form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was controllers,models,views names ...

```
class GalGallerifficViewGalleryItems
```

this naming working fine on wamp server but when uploading to the hosting account (apache ) it does not
it should follow camel naming

```
class GalGallerifficViewGalleryitems
```

I hope it will help other developers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by

using

```
class GalGallerifficViewGalleryitems
```

instead of

```
class GalGallerifficViewGalleryItems
```

For that you will also need to change

```
public function getModel($name = 'galleryitems', $prefix = 'GalGallerifficModel')
{
    $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, array('ignore_request' => true));
    return $model;
}
```

in controller file.